# "Coded UI Test Builder" Crosshairs not available in IE

Tags: visual-studio-2010, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to test out Visual Studio's automated testing capabilities for a web application and the [Coded UI Test Builder](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2010/11/03/coded-ui-tests-1.aspx) looks like it might be promising.

I can get it to record and playback actions, but I can't figure out how to use the crosshairs button to create assertions.

For example, in [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Visual-Studio-2012-Premium-and-Ultimate-Overview/Visual-Studio-Ultimate-2012-Easily-testing-user-interfaces-with-Coded-UI-tests) the presenter starts a recording, then opens IE and is able to select different UI elements for assertions. When I do this however, the crosshairs get greyed out as soon as I open IE.

Do I need to install a plugin or some other tool to make the Coded UI Test Builder able to access the DOM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I think I figured it out. It looks like you have to pause the recording and then click "Generate Code" to get the crosshairs to be selectable. Then you create your assertion as a separate step and "Generate Code" for that.

I'm not sure if this is what your workflow is supposed to be, but it's working for me consistently.